# RedirectMatch old product urls (without ID) to new url with basic (using ID) structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'am facing a problem with our PrestaShop 1.7.5 installation.

About 2 weeks ago, I tried to upgrade our PrestaShop version (from 1.7.4 to 1.7.5). Unfortunately 1 important module is not working any longer (override of the dispatcher is outdated), this module generates SEO-friendly URLs, without ID's in the URL, like this: `domain/{category}/{rewrite}`

We prefer to do no roll-back and are considering two options.

**Option 1: Redirect all old product URLs to the new URLs**

Old url format: 
`domain/{category}/{rewrite}`

New url format:
`domain/{parent-category}/{sub-category}/{ID}-{ID_product_attribute}-{rewrite}`

**Option 2: Redirect all 404 to searchcontroller**

By using the keywords from the URL, to achieve this, we can use the part `{category}` & `{rewrite}`

I've tried a lot of small codes, which I've found on the net, like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search/$1/1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&category=web&d=$2 [NC,L]
```

I did read the manual on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html
I do understand how to redirect a simple page to another... but I get stuck...

This is my .htacces file as it is now (generated by prestashop):

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

#Domain: domain.be
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be$
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Etag
</IfModule>
FileETag none
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf application/x-font-ttf font/otf application/x-font-otf font/opentype image/svg+xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Mitch, Can you please post your full .htaccess? it would help :-)

Comment: @BrunoLeveque, I`m using the standard htaccess file, generated by prestashop. I edited the first post.

Comment: If the module you're using is this one https://mypresta.eu/modules/seo/pretty-clean-urls-pro.html
it already has a fix for 1.7.5 - "To use module in PrestShop 1.7.5 you must update it to at least 2.7.0 version."

Comment: @yasoh This is the module indeed... But I don`t like to buy it everytime I would like to update our prestashop... So I prefer to use the default url dispatcher & redirect the old urls to the new...

Comment: @Mitch you should be able to update it without buying the module again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works and will permanently redirect old product URLs to new ones (Option #1):**

1. Place the script below in your PrestaShop root folder
2. Optional: Edit the `id_shop` and `id_lang` parameters to match your configuration
3. Launch it and copy/paste the result to your .htaccess file, just after `RewriteEngine on` - delete the script
4. Voilà!

**Script:**

```
<?php

include('config/config.inc.php');
include('init.php');

$context = Context::getContext();

$products = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
SELECT p.id_product, pl.link_rewrite prod_url, cl.link_rewrite cat_url
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang cl ON (cl.id_category = p.id_category_default)
WHERE p.active = 1 AND cl.id_lang = 1 AND cl.id_shop = 1 AND pl.id_lang = 1 AND cl.id_shop = 1');

foreach ($products as $p)
{
    $new_url = $context->link->getProductLink(new Product((int)$p['id_product']));
    echo 'RewriteRule ^'.$p['cat_url'].'/'.$p['prod_url'].'$ '.$new_url.' [L,R=301]<br />';
}
```

**Output (on a PrestaShop demo store with only 2 products):**

```
RewriteRule ^men/hummingbird-printed-t-shirt$ http://localhost/prestashop/1-hummingbird-printed-t-shirt.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^women/brown-bear-printed-sweater$ http://localhost/prestashop/2-brown-bear-printed-sweater.html [L,R=301]
```

**.htaccess file after copy/paste:**

```
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

# Permanent redirections
RewriteRule ^men/hummingbird-printed-t-shirt$ http://localhost/prestashop/1-hummingbird-printed-t-shirt.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^women/brown-bear-printed-sweater$ http://localhost/prestashop/2-brown-bear-printed-sweater.html [L,R=301]

#Domain: localhost
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/prestashop/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]
...
```

Option #2 does not seem viable to me in terms of conversion rate.

I hope this helps!

If not, I'd ask the module's developer for an updated version, $25 seems a reasonable cost to upgrade given how time-consuming this would be for you.

Comment: Just to be correct: the module clean URL's is doing a very good job & the support of the developer vekia is awesome, its really worth the € 25. Never had a problem. But, prestashop is moving fast. And except of the theme I would like to use less modules from thirth party developers. Especially modules that are using overrides of the prestashop corefiles.

Comment: Milos (aka Vekia) is indeed one of the pillars of the PrestaShop community!

Comment: First, you should always look after this file until it is deleted (because it does not auto-create). Moreover, this method is suitable for a small number of redirects, not for high numbers.This will slow down your site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435482/is-it-okay-to-have-a-very-long-htaccess-file#answer-4435531 .This is not a good method. The best way is to do the same in  a controller,  so that all requests are not involved in this process.

Comment: @MahdiShad, Thank you for your kind words. I'm not sure I understood your answer, but anyway, your suggestion would double the necessary resources, the controller would have to be called twice (to trigger the 301 and a second time to process). Even if Mitch would have 10,000+ rewrite rules, it would just take a few microseconds to process vs 2 x ~400ms. Thank you for the down-vote anyway, really appreciate it.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque, Sorry for my bad English :) . "Creating a huge .htaccess can have a serious performance impact on your system as it is read linearly for all requests, at least until a rule with the L attribute (Last Rule) is matched.". for example: PrestaShop.com has 60 requests on "home page", In this case, checking 10,000 rewrite rules repeats 60 times (60*10000).  The next point is that, even on pages that are not needed (blogs, categories), all 10,000 lines are checked for all requests.

Comment: But using the module, we can override dispatcher and do the same process there. The fact is that I do not have any benchmarks, but the use of the module seems to be more optimal and more stable. The last point: 
I'm really kind, but Google translator looks angry :)) we love you on IPresta.ir

Comment: @BrunoLeveque Also on your way: it seems better to transfer rules to httpd.conf file.

Comment: @MahdiShad, Thank you. I used JMeter to benchmark your solution and it was 99.7% slower. Mitch mentioned he'd like to use less modules, so override might not be best for him. I recently saw a  a PrestaShop store with 60,000 permanent redirects on Nginx and a $10/mo VPS, even though it's clearly not best practice and memory-consuming, it was still blazing fast. Regarding static content (Images, CSS, JS), the best solution is to serve them through a CDN whenever possible.

Comment: I am not a programmer or developer. But of course I love that our store achieves the best possible performance (also another reason to use less thirth party modules). The use of the redirects is only temporary, until Google understands the structure of the webshop. I did a "time to first byte" check with the + - 5000 redirects and 1 without. Without the redirects the result is: 2137 ms - With the redirects via .htacces the result is: 2770 ms. There is indeed a delay, but, in my opinion, it does not, outweigh the benefits of the redirect long term...

Comment: Indeed, 2+ sec for your TTFB seems really high. In case you can access Apache configuration, try moving the rules to the vhost configuration (as per @MahdiShad suggestion). I'd be happy to help you boosting your performance, can we switch to the PrestaShop SO chat room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192800/prestashop

Answer (score 0):

Given that product IDs have been removed from your URLs, I think you can not redirect them through Htaccess.
tip: You can't add your url rules line by line in the htaccess file. It will slow down your site. All rules are checked at any request from your site (css links, js links, images , etc)

To do this, you need to have a new controller checking and redirecting the URLs. In fact, you need another module to fix this problem. Your override must be reversed.

--That's why we never advise our customers to remove ID from PrestaShop URLs.